# button and pencolor not working in python

Tags: python, python-turtle

so there is this project im working on in python so basically i have a turtle which using the arrow keys i can move and it leaves a line behind it using the pen color and i have a red button what i want to do is when this red buttton is pressed the pencolor changes from black to red i tried everything and nothing works please someone help here is the code

```
import turtle
from turtle import *


tim = Screen()
screen = Screen()

screenn = turtle.Screen()


pensize(5)
shape("turtle")
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
FONT_SIZE = 12
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'bold')
turtle.pencolor("black")

def red():
    turtle.pencolor("red")

button1 = Turtle()
button1.hideturtle()
button1.shape('square')
button1.fillcolor('red')
button1.penup()
button1.goto(150, 150)
button1.write("circle",align='center', font = FONT)
button1.sety(150 + CURSOR_SIZE + FONT_SIZE)
button1.onclick(red)
button1.showturtle()
```

button 1 is the red button i want to be able to use to change the color of the pen but its not working
there is also more code down that makes the movement work but i did not include that here.

Answer (score 0):

The below rework of your code should do what you want:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
FONT_SIZE = 12
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'bold')

def red(x, y):
    turtle.pencolor('red')

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.pensize(5)
turtle.shape('turtle')

button = Turtle()
button.hideturtle()
button.shape('square')
button.fillcolor('red')
button.penup()

button.goto(150, 150 - CURSOR_SIZE - FONT_SIZE)
button.write("red pen", align='center', font=FONT)
button.sety(150)

button.onclick(red)
button.showturtle()

screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.forward(10), 'Right')
screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.backward(10), 'Left')
screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 10), 'Up')
screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - 10), 'Down')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

I put back in crude turtle motion routines for testing purposes.  When you define an `onclick()` handler, it should take two arguments for the X and Y position of the click, even it doesn't need them to do what it does.